# How can I tell when a function is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: calculus

I have the function $f(x) = 5x^{2/3} - 5x^{5/3}$. I can differentiate it and find the zeros of $f'(x)$ which equals $\frac{10}{3\sqrt[3]{x}} - \frac{25\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{3}$, but I'm not sure how to tell when it is increasing or decreasing. I have even graphed it in Desmos, but even though it only seems to be increasing on the interval $(0, \frac{2}{5})$ this is apparently not the case.

*How can I tell when this function is increasing or decreasing?*

**Differentiate:**

$$\frac{d}{dx} (5x^{2/3} - 5x^{5/3}) = \frac{10}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{2}{3}x^{2/3}=\frac{10}{3\sqrt[3]{x}} - \frac{25\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{3}$$

**Find Zeros:**

$$\frac{10}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{2}{3}x^{2/3}=0 \to \frac{10}{3\sqrt[3]{x}} =\frac{25\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{3} \to 30 = 25(x^{2/3})(3x^{2/3}) \to 30 = 75(x^{2/3})(x^{1/3}) \to \frac{30}{75}=x$$

$$x = \frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: Try this [link](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/calculus/calculus/applications-of-the-derivative/increasing-decreasing-functions) they show you how to use derivatives to find where a function is increasing or decreasing and also have two examples.

Comment: There's a theorem to the effect that if the derivative is positive throughout an interval, then the function is strictly increasing in that interval, and analogously for "derivative is negative" and "strictly decreasing". One common method that uses these results is to determine where the derivative is zero and where the derivative is undefined, and if what's left over separates into non-overlapping intervals, then you can use a standard precalculus "sign chart" method. Several such examples [are described in detail here](http://mathforum.org/kb/plaintext.jspa?messageID=5324603).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is strictly increasing between the points where it has a derivative of 0.

Therefor, let’s say you set $f‘(x) = 0$ and got x = 1 and x = 3 as a solution.

Between $-\infty$ and $1$, it would be either strictly growing or falling. 
Same counts for the Intervall between $1$ and $3$ and the Intervall from $3$ to $\infty$

Now to check if the function grows in these intervals, take any x value inside that Intervall and check if the derivative at that point is greater than $0$. if it is, it’s growing. If not, it’s falling. If it’s $0$, you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Factor your function first.
$$f(x) = 5x^{2/3}(1-x).$$
At $x = 0$, $f(x)=0$, and at $x = 1$, $f(x) = 0$.
This function has only two roots at $x = 0,1$.  You found that $f'(2/5) = 0$.
Therefore, it must be decreasing on $(2/5,\infty)$.